# Image in div not shown

Tags: html, css

Why won't it show the whole original picture?

```css
.test {
  background: url("http://i27.tinypic.com/28ktoh.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Problem is that is doesn't show anything, if you type something in the div it shows a little bit of the image. I want it to include the full picture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fit background image to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200204/fit-background-image-to-div)

Answer (score 1):

[**Here is the working demo**](http://jsbin.com/isuha3)

You need to specify the `height`

```
.test { 
  background: url("http://i27.tinypic.com/28ktoh.jpg") no-repeat;
  overflow:auto;
  height:500px;
}
```

Comment: doesn't the width need to specified as well?

Comment: @pixeltocode: That's upto OP. I just showed him what he was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the `div`. The `div` will not be higher than you tell it to be or higher than it needs to be.

Comment: Indeed. Could you add that if he wants to show the whole image, he may be better off using `<img>` (if appropriate)?

Comment: @MvanGeest: He's using it as a background image, so I'm not sure that's appropriate here.

Comment: @MvanGeest: I'm guessing he already knows about the `<img>` tag if he's dealing with CSS. :)

Comment: He could, but maybe he's making the wrong choice. Anyway, this discussion is now in the comments, so he'll see the pointer and look it up if he finds it necessary. (I meant to be gender-neutral, but writing *(s)he* is annoying. *He* can mean *she* anywhere I wrote it.)