# Fit background image to div

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a background image in the following div, but the image gets cut off:

```
 <div style='text-align:center;background-image: url(/media/img_1_bg.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;width:450px;height:900px;' id="mainpage" align="center">
```

Is there a way to show the background image without cutting it off?

Comment: Is the image bigger than the div?

Comment: yes the image is bigger than the div

Comment: background-image:url(/media/img_1_bg.jpg); 
background-size: contain; background-repeat:no-repeat;

Answer (score 956, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property, which is now [supported by most browsers](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts).

To scale the background image to fit inside the div:

```css
background-size: contain;
```

To scale the background image to cover the whole div:

```css
background-size: cover;
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/wGRD7/) or runnable snippet:

```css
#imagecontainer {
  background: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagecontainer"></div>
```

There also exists a [filter for IE 5.5+ support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2991623/645956), as well as [vendor prefixes for some older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 200):

If what you need is the image to have the same dimensions of the div, I think this is the most elegant solution:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

If not, the answer by @grc is the most appropriated one.

Source:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: but this would stretch the image... is there a way to fit the background image without stretching it?

Comment: Aspect ratio lost however.

Comment: @Learner If you change the dimensions of a image without cropping the image the aspect ratio will be lost 99% of the time. It's common sense.

Answer (score 37):

You can use this attributes:

```
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

and you code is then like this:

```
 <div style="text-align:center;background-image: url(/media/img_1_bg.jpg); background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;" id="mainpage">
```

Answer (score 15):

```
background-position-x: center;
background-position-y: center;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please explain your answer to make it helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 10):

you also use this:

```
background-size:contain;
height: 0;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 66,64%;
```

I don't know your div-values, but let's assume you've got those.

```
height: auto;
max-width: 600px;
```

Again, those are just random numbers.
It could quite hard to make the background-image (if you would want to) with a fixed width for the div, so better use max-width. And actually it isn't complicated to fill a div with an background-image, just make sure you style the parent element the right way, so the image has a place it can go into.

Chris

Comment: Link to a highly voted answer that talks about this solution in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size and shows you how to calculate the `padding-top`.

Answer (score 8):

try any of the following,

```
background-size: contain;
background-size: cover;
background-size: 100%;

.container{
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

The `background-size` property specifies the size of the background images.

There are different syntaxes you can use with this property: the keyword syntax ("auto", "cover" and "contain"), the one-value syntax (sets the width of the image (height becomes "auto"), the two-value syntax (first value: width of the image, second value: height).

- **percentage** - Sets the width and height of the background image in percent of the parent element.
- **cover** - Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges
- **contain** - Resize the background image to make sure the image is fully visible

For more: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please explain your answer to make it helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

Alternative:

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please explain your answer to make it helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

you can also try this, set background size as cover and to get it look nicer also set background position center like so :

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center ;
```