# how to make the background image fit with the div?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fit background image to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200204/fit-background-image-to-div)

how to make the background image fit with the div ?, because in firefox, there's no problem at all, unlike with IE8,IE9

here's the code

```
div.helpcontent{
    height:120px;
    display:none;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000000;
}


div.helpcontent{
    margin: 0 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 242px;
    text-align: center;
    //background: #ffffff;
    background: url(../images/helpBg.gif) no-repeat;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Fit with the div"

Answer (score 1):

In CSS3 you can use the following css :

```
div.helpcontent
{
    background:url(../images/helpBg.gif);
    -moz-background-size:100% 100%; /* Firefox 3.6 */
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```