# how to show full image when resizing react

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm React Beginner, i have two questions, first question: here i'm using 'allotment' to split two images (resize), you can change the size of images by pulling from middle of those two images

my problem here is, when i'm pulling to left or right to see whole picture, it does not show whole picture it goes over the bottom of page, any idea why?

Second question: below the images I have div which shows with  `height:` 93%`

my question is why `height:93` shows the div and height: `100%` won't ? shouldn't `height:100%` take the rest of space left?

try it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-star-1wxx12?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { Allotment } from "allotment";
import "./styles.css";
import "allotment/dist/style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ background: "blue", minHeight: "42px" }}>Monitor</div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%", background: "darkblue" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            border: "1px solid orange",
            width: "100px",
            height: "100%",
            background: "gray"
          }}
        >
          side content
        </div>
        <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%",
              background: "red",
              border: "3px solid yellow"
            }}
          >
            <Allotment>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "93%",
                    flexDirection: "column"
                  }}
                >
                  <div style={{ flex: "1" }}>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./the-mandalorian.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                </div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "93%",
                    flexDirection: "column"
                  }}
                >
                  <div style={{ flex: "1" }}>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./nature.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                </div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
            </Allotment>
          </div>{" "}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

English is not my mother language so there could be mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

### [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) can help you with that

(Please remove all the styles you have given your images and apply these)

```css
img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Video showing the solution a-work](https://streamable.com/8e2ata)

---

> "my question is why `height:93%` shows the div and height: `100%` won't? 
> shouldn't `height:100%` take the rest of space left?"

If only `width` or `height` are defined without the other, the image's aspect ratio will be preserved and in your case, will result in an unwanted rendering outcome.

since your design have horizontal 2 panes, this leaves very little space for the image to span across the horizontal area, meaning the aspect-ratio of the viewable area is much higher than wide.

You almost always want to maintain the original aspect-ratio, especially for pictures.

---

Relevant links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682038/104380
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Comment: in that case i would need object-fit: contain; but then again image goes over border

Comment: @walee - I've tested on your example exactly what I've told you here and it works perfectly as you wished. what is the problem now?

Comment: I've added a video link to the answer to show you