# Nested div floating outside of containing div after adding text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem that once I use `jQuery's .html()` to insert a paragraph into a nested div. It's causing it to float outside of it's containing div. I've tried playing with the margins and padding of both divs but to no avail. I'm new to **javascript/jQuery** and would really like to understand why this is happening. Thanks for the help in advance.

Here's a screenshot link:

[image]

Here's my html:

```
<div class="selectHero">
  <div id="ironMan"></div>
  <div id="capAmerica"></div>
  <div id="thor"></div>
  <div id="winterSoldier"></div>
</div>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
$('#ironMan').html("<p>IronMan</p>"+"<p> health: "+ironMan.health+"</p>");
```

Here's my css:

```
.selectHero {
  max-height: 250px;
  max-width: 900px;
}

#ironMan {
  background-image: url("../images/ironMan.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

Comment: please add into jsfiddle. as per your HTML its not clear to understand. You can check your display property to inline-block to other via firebug

Answer (score 0):

Try using `background-size` property. I guess similar question is posted here -

[Fit background image to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200204/fit-background-image-to-div)

Comment: I'm already using background-size though? and my backgrounds are sized the way I wish them to be.