# How to stretch data-src image to a div tag width and height?

Tags: html

I have a tag such below :

```
<div data-thumb="http://aeo-azsharghi.ir/images/photo_2017-07-26_08-35-
    11_th.jpg" style="background-size: cover;" data-src="http://aeo-
    azsharghi.ir/images/photo_2017-07-26_08-35-11.jpg" data-alignment="topCenter">
</div>
```

My need is fitting image as a background image to `div`.

Comment: try setting max-width:100% and max-height:100%

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript libraries with this? If so could you please tell us what they are and show any code that's related to adding an image background?

Comment: actually it is joomla's slideshow ck module. I want to streach slideshow images

Comment: I tired too much to do this. but it is not working. I added "data-width" and data-height" property too but the result is the same as without the parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this post solution and it worked for me.
[Fit background image to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200204/fit-background-image-to-div)

```
background-size: contain;
background-size: cover;
background-size: 100%;

.container{
    background-size: 100%;
}
```