# Background image displays wrong, don't know what to do

Tags: html, css, background-image

i'm pretty new to CSS but I made something in illustrator (web)and wanted to put this as background-image in css. I've put the image in a `<div>` and CSS in I just put `background-image: url(berg.jpg)`, i'm sure the url is correct, but it doesn't display anything. I've put `height: 100%` in css after that and it showed up but it was all zoomed in and only displays a small corner of the picture because of the zoom. How can I display this correctly? The image size is width: 1366px; height:768px.

Sorry if this is already asked but I couldn't seem to find it. Thx on advance.

Comment: Posted your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fit background image to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200204/fit-background-image-to-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is displaying as full size.  If you add the background-size attribute to your css, you can define the size.

See this link for all `background-size` options:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

You can also define the `background-position` to have image centered, etc.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

---

**CSS example**

```
    #problem-image {
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463852247062-1bbca38f7805?auto=format&fit=crop&w=2255&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D');
    }

    #correct-image {
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463852247062-1bbca38f7805?auto=format&fit=crop&w=2255&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D');
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center center;
    }
```

See jsfiddle for full working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/3o8b2e4s/

Comment: Thank you so much, will mark this as answer in some minutes!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put `bakcground-size: cover;` in your CSS code and this will ocupe all background of your div independent of width or height.