# Make resizable background image fit screen's size in width

Tags: html, css

Here is my CSS code:

```
.TabTop {
background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/5qOZqaY.png");
width: 1855px;
height: 168px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.TabMid {
background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/6uMuiY4.jpg");
width: 1855px;
height: 100%;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
.TabBot {
background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/5Psk33C.png");
width: 1855px;
height: 237px;
}
```

And here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="TaTop"></div>
<div class="TabMid"></div>
<div class="TabBot"></div>
```

Right now it looks like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKtcM.jpg

As you can see on the right there is a gap.

I would like all 3 parts of the image to be centered and resized in width according to the size of the user's computer monitor size.

I also tried background-size: cover
it doesn't seem to work.

How could I do that?

Comment: have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200204/fit-background-image-to-div) ?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help.

Comment: What does the structure of your html look like for this container?

Comment: <div class="TabTop"></div>
    <div class="TabMid"></div>
    <div class="TabBot"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Using `background-size: cover` should do the trick.
But it won't give you that much control.

For that you should use Media queries and some more background properties.

`@media only screen and (max-width:420px) {
    .TabTop {
        background-position: center
    }
}`

You could try more media query sizes to get more control on how your image should look on different device.

Here's [Media queries guide](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/) for more examples.

Comment: background-size: cover doesn't work for me, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ya go for media queries it'll give you more control for each screen size. Basically there are 4-5 media queries that should handle all screen types

Comment: Go through guide I've posted in answer

Comment: I just tried the media query tag for large screens on the top background image part, and the image just completely vanished instead of scaling on the width.

Comment: Here is the code I used:
    @media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
    .TabTop {
        background-image: url("./images/Halo_Top.png");
        background-position: center
    }
}

Comment: Also add background-size to it

Comment: That background-position : center; is example purpose.
You'll have to set different sizes for different screen size as per you requirement

Comment: background-position is used to position image on div.

Answer (score 0):

you lack a **'b'** in Class of **'TabTop'** and if you use 100% in Height it usually does not work if the parent has some class that references that value like `position:relative`.

```css
.TabTop {
background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/5qOZqaY.png");
width: 1855px;
height: 168px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.TabMid {
background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/6uMuiY4.jpg");
width: 1855px;
height: 100vh; /* alternative for % */
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
.TabBot {
background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/5Psk33C.png");
width: 1855px;
height: 237px;
}
```

```html
<div class="TabTop"></div>
<div class="TabMid"></div>
<div class="TabBot"></div>
```