# How to make an svg image as a background image with react and Tailwind css?

Tags: reactjs, svg, responsive-design, background-image, tailwind-css

i am implementing a reponsive website with react and tailwind , i have an SVG image which i want to make it as a background image for a main tag but it doesn't work . I followed the tailwind docs and added this code to my taliwind.config.js

```
 theme: {
   extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
                         'hero-pattern': "url('/public/background.svg)"
                        }
            }
         }
```

and using bg-hero-pattern does not display anything .
I tried another option which is the style attribute in my tag it displays the image but it does not cover all the parent tag although i am using bg-cover and bg-no-repeat
this is my code :

```
<main className="w-screen h-screen  ">
    <div className="h-screen w-screen bg-no-repeat bg-cover"                    
         style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${background})` }}>
      {/* Content */}
      
      <div className="px-4 py-6 sm:px-0">
        <div className="border-4 border-dashed border-gray-200 rounded-lg h-96"> 
     </div>
      </div>
      {/* <!-- /End content --> */}
    </div>
  </main>
```

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: You have a stray ' in the example:`url('/public/background.svg)` -> `url(/public/background.svg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've defined it in the `tailwind.config.js` file like  you mentioned as

```
theme: {
   extend: {
      backgroundImage:
         {
           'hero_pattern': "url('/public/background.svg)"
         }
     }
 }
```

The you can simple use it as

```
<div class="bg-hero_pattern">
   ...
   ...
</div>
```

> I have changed name from hero-pattern to hero_pattern

Comment: yes i did that but the image never fit all the parent div ther is always left space

Comment: Try to check whether the image is of complete resolution of 1920*1080 for laptop screen

Comment: so if it is not of complete resolution couldn't it be displayed even it becomes blurry ?

Comment: Here Resolution, i mean size of image If it's not proper size then it may not cover full div

Comment: thank you sir the problem was with the resolution i tried a bigger image and it worked

Comment: Happy to help you buddy

Answer (score 4):

The simplest and best solution could be using an arbitrary value. You can do something like this

```html
<div className="bg-[url('../images/background-image.svg')]">
```

You can find more details about arbitrary values over [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values) and you require tailwind version 3+ to use it.

Comment: The problem that the image never fit or cover the parent div even with  bg-cover

Comment: You will find solution for this over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200204/fit-background-image-to-div

Answer (score 2):

I tend to avoid using background images these days and use `grid` instead. Just layer the grid cells one on top of the other.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/gOFytBrc4G

```html
<div class="grid h-64 bg-gray-400 p-5">
  <img src="/img/logo.svg" class="col-start-1 row-start-1 self-center opacity-25" alt="Tailwind Play" />
  <div class="col-start-1 row-start-1">
    <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold">This is my heading</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can wrap the `img` in a `div` if that gives you more control.

It should give the same end result, and I find you have more control this way anyway.

Comment: The problem that the image never fit or cover the parent div even with bg-cover

Comment: What is happening instead? Are you able to share the svg image? If the svg has width and height inside the code then it will be a fixed size, like this https://play.tailwindcss.com/NSy0RGFr3v. But in the original example it has no width and height so essentially it is acting like `object-contain` and filling the space