# Unsure why CSS object-fit property is not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to cover a flex-box container with an image but the CSS property `object-fit` doesn't seem to be working and is not fitting my image which is 1536 x 1536 which is much bigger than what the dimensions are for the container. This is what it looks like:

[image]

And this is what the image looks like:

[image]

How can I fit this image into that flex box container?

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(244, 247, 252, 0.5) 0%, rgba(244, 247, 252, 0.5) 100%);
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 20vh;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20vh;
  font-size: 30px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.sdg1 {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1536.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div className="flex-container">
  <div className="sdg1"></div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
  <div>SDG</div>
</div>
```

Comment: onbject fit is for an img element not for a background image. the background image does not influence the element itself. As the name indicates it is just background.

Comment: Is there a way to fit that image in that container then?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size is what you're looking for in this case

Comment: It already does by default. At least if you use `class` instead of `className`. Do you use react?

Comment: Yes it's react, I did `background-size: contain;` and it worked!

Comment: background-size: contain/cover; https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200264/17447

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object-fit` should be used on `img` elements to determine how they will be displayed inside of their own "container".

For this to work, you must replace your `<div>` element with an `<img>` element. Here is an example of how object-fit works:

```css
.contained {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/19/15/46/labrador-retriever-1210559__480.jpg" class="contained">
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/caroselli/pen/NWYgpwj)